# Host Named Site Collection Is Not Accessible

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When creating a host named site collection following the instructions of this article, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952(v=office.15).aspx#section2a, I received a warning:

> WARNING: The port specified for the new host header site does not
>   match any known bindings in the specified Web Application.  The new
>   site will not be accessible if the Web Application is not extended to
>   an IIS Web Site serving this port.

the command in question was similar to this:

> New-SPSite 'http://portal1.mydomain.com' -HostHeaderWebApplication
>   'http://clients.mydomain.com:18764' -Name 'Portal1' -Description
>   'Portal1 root' -OwnerAlias 'domain\username' -language 1033 -Template
>   'STS#0'

what do I need to do to make the site available? the site collection I created I want to access as portal1.mydomain.com

I created a web application for containing all of our extranet clients. each client is to have a host named site collection.

if the solution involves alternate access mappings, what exactly gets mapped to what?

sharepoint 2013 sp1, windows server 2012 r2, sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all requests on port 18764 being answered by a SharePoint Web Application?

If your web application was created with a fixed host header you need to extend it so it answers to all requests on the port you are using.

Also, the host named site collections your create must use the same port as the Web Application that will answer the requests

So the SPSite URL should be as below (if all requests on that port are being accepted)

> New-SPSite 'http://portal1.mydomain.com:18764'
>   -HostHeaderWebApplication 'http://clients.mydomain.com:18764' -Name 'Portal1' -Description 'Portal1 root' -OwnerAlias 'domain\username'
>   -language 1033 -Template 'STS#0'

Comment: if i understand your first question, the answer is yes, but they should be directed to the appropriate portalx.mydomain.com. in other words, i have 1 web application on port 18764 which will have multiple site collections. portal1.mydomain.com is for site collection 1, portal2.mydomain.com is for site collection 2, and so on. 

the syntax you provided avoids the warning error. unfortunately i still cannot access the site collection via portal1.mydomain.com. however, that could be due to dns configuration errors. thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to add the port to the URL as http://portal1.mydomain.com:18764, or change the listening port of your WEb Applicaiton to the port 80

Comment: i tried that, but it doesn't work. the background is that  i added a new web app for these site collections. i think i need to update dns. i hope it is that simple.

yes - i need to change the listening port. i don't want clients to have to know a port number. i was just accepting the defaults provided by the collection form - not always a good idea :-o.

Comment: Registering the name in the DNS is also something that needs to be done. If you publish your SharePoint server by using a reverse proxy or firewall solution, you can have it receive the requests on port 80 and then forward the requests to your 18764 port on the SharePoint server.